# Rails 4: Retrieving Post Notifications (Listener)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, model

I've setup a Purchase Model & Purchases Controller to allow users buy Items from my Rails application via PayPal (IPN).
Everything works fine apart from listening for PayPal's IPN answer.
How can you actually listen for this post notification properly / what have I done wrong?

**Weird is that if I link a `return_url` to `/hook` it works, but the `notify_url` seemingly does not work.**
Why does PayPal even pass the parameters to the Return URL? - you don't want the User to have to use the Return URL to unlock his bought items.

1. Opening PayPal in new Tab with Button => works
2. Passing necessary Item information to PayPal => works
3. Buy Item with PayPal => works
4. List item as `:status => "Completed"` in Database => does not work!

User Model:

```
has_many :purchases
```

Purchase Model:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tool
    belongs_to :user

    def paypal_url(return_path)
        values = {
            business: "merchant@example.com",
            cmd: "_xclick",
            upload: 1,
            invoice: id,
            amount: tool.price,
            item_name: tool.title,
            notify_url: "http://5947992e.ngrok.io/hook" #Test Server
        }
        "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
    end
end
```

Purchases Controller:

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @purchase = Purchase.new(:tool_id => params[:tool_id], :user_id => current_user.id)
        if @purchase.save
            redirect_to @purchase.paypal_url(purchase_path(@purchase))
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
    def hook
        params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
        status = params[:payment_status]
        if status == "Completed"
            @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:invoice])
            @purchase.update_attributes(status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now)
            @purchase.save!
            @user = @tool.user
            @user.earned_money += @tool.price
            @user.save!
        end
        render nothing: true
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
post "/purchases/:id" => "purchases#show"
post "/hook" => "purchases#hook"
```

Item Show View (haml):

```
= link_to image_tag('paypal.png'), new_purchase_path(:tool_id => @tool.id), target: "_blank"
```

Thanks in advance for each answer! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: `@purchase.update_attributes(status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now)` - Here you are trying to update the status as `Completed` , can you try this with `update_attributes!` ?  This would give you the error for which the update is not working!

Comment: This line works properly, cause somehow if I use a `return_url`(Paypal) it's passing the parameters to my server and the db gets updated as expected. The problem is just that I have to make a mistake with calling the `notify_url` cause with that nothing gets updated. The Controller Action stays the same.